# Run an OpenCV code on cloud machine [Azure]

Tags: python, c++, opencv, azure, cloud

I'm new to Azure but already have an 8-core machine running there with Ubuntu 12.04 and OpenCV properly installed. Also, i have an executable (C++) that receives an image as argument and prints the result on terminal (in case, if the object was found or not in the image).

So, what i need is to call this executable from my notebook to another C++ code. Basically speaking, I need to run a program on my notebook that call another one on Azure, passing an image as argument. I do not have much experience on this area, so all help is welcome. I heard i need to do this using Python, so how would it be ? And why ?

Thanks!!

Comment: At least you can comment the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in whatever language you want. The answer to make 2 machines "talk" via Internet is always sockets, can't be done other way.

If I were you I'll do it this way:

A program in Azure listens to a port (server) and when you want your notebook software to process an image, that software will connect to that port and send the image, then the server will process it using OpenCV and return the results to the client if needed so.

Other way can be that the server software queries a database or looks for a directory if there are new images each X seconds, and your client software will upload to that directory the image vía ftp or scp (more secure) or whatever. This way will be more difficult to retrieve the results.

Now, you need to know about language programming to develop this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I'll try to use sockets, but what must i do to communicate with Azure using ports ? Something related to Endpoints ? As said before, i do not have much experience on that, so any help or directions to the subject would be nice. And one more thing.. Can i do this only in C++ and the ports/communication troubles only in network configuration ?

Comment: You can do it in any server, virtual server, dedicated server, whatever server as long as you can run your own software. Simply you have to create a server in any language (c++ is a good choice because of its performance, but a bad choice because of your lack of knowledge because is one of the hardest programming language nowadays). You have to code everything by yourself or search a lot for frameworks that do it, but altough you search for frameworks you have to code to implement them so I'll go for coding it yourself because a server is really easy to program. Also, i'll choose node.js...

Comment: ...because of it's versatility. You can edit scripts "on the fly" without needing to recompile them and the knowledge about variables is easier to understand, so your code will be less likely to fail. In Azure endpoints are simply opening ports. Because of security when a program listens to a port in an Azure server, it can't be accessed externally if you don't open the port, but you have to code all the "client <-> server" communication. If you don't have experience this won't be easy and also won't be something that you will finish completely in an intensive week of work, you will have to...

Comment: ...deal with errors and fix them all the time (and when I say all the time, I say more than 50% of the time you are going to spend will be fixing errors instead of simply coding). I'll try to get you in the right direction: First search for a node.js tutorial and learn how functions, variables and callbacks works, doing some homework or examples to understand them better. After that search for a node.js "client and server" example, look at it and try to understand each line of code (EVERYTHING! Don't miss a line or you will be lost). I remark the "understand everything" because...

Comment: ...coding is not magic. Coding is a serie of instructions that have a perfect logic between them. If you don't understand a line of code the logic will be broken, so you surely will be lost soon or later. Well, I can't say much more. Good luck in your odyssey @Thigoo ;-)

Comment: Also, don't think that coding is a lose of time. Nowadays having knowledge about coding is really useful, specially if you work with computers. I love code bots and half of my life are scripts that work for me when I encounter a repetitive task xD

Comment: Thanks a lot Jorge!! Great help, and for sure i'll try to do it!